# É possível fazer streaming de um sinal de vídeo localmente para um browser?

Tags: html5, navegador-de-internet

É possível exibir o sinal de TV aberta utilizando uma placa de captura e exibir dentro de um navegador web utilizando HTML5 ou JavaScript?

Considerando que uso Ubuntu.

Comment: No caso de smart TV é possivel usando essa chamada, sabem dizer?

Answer (score 4):

Depende do driver da placa de vídeo, dá. Muitos drivers podem funcionar de maneira idêntica a uma webcam, então tanto o Flash quanto o HTML5 têm acesso.

Exemplo de vídeo em HTML5:

```html
<video autoplay id="vid" style="display:none;"></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>
<button onclick="snapshot()">Salvar um quadro</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var video = document.querySelector("#vid");
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var localMediaStream = null;

    var onCameraFail = function (e) {
        console.log('A camera nao funcionou.', e);
    };

    function snapshot() {
        if (localMediaStream) {
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, function (stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        localMediaStream = stream;
    }, onCameraFail);

</script>
```

> Verifique se a opção “media.navigator.enabled” está ligada no "about:config", no chrome.

<sub>Fonte do exemplo: http://www.scottpreston.com/articles/1442.php</sub>

Comment: Conheçe alguma placa de captura que o driver faça o mesmo que o driver da webcam ?

Comment: Estou usando uma AverTV .. instalei aqui no pc só que apenas funciona com o softwares desta placa.

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção é utilizar softwares para isso como:

- [Windows Media Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17792)
- Media Server (versões de servidores do windows)
- [Flash Media Live Encoder (na minha opinião o melhor)](http://www.adobe.com/it/products/flash-media-encoder.html)
- softwares de terceiros..

O Windows Media Encoder, pega o vídeo da sua placa e transformar em streaming.
Assim você poderá chamar qualquer player tanto em html5 quanto html antigo o vídeo.

Porém consome muita banda, eu com a NET 20MB consigo umas 4~6 pessoas assistindo a 640x420 com qualidade razoável, acho que era uns 480kbps